# Calculating the probability that a cord makes a knot

Tags: probability, physics, knot-theory

I use earphones to listen to music. The cord connected to the earphones often gets entangled in my pocket and makes a knot, which I always find hard to untangle.

How can I define and calculate the probability that my cord spontaneously makes a knot?

Thank you.

Comment: Take a look at [this interesting paper on Spontaneous knotting of an agitated string.](http://www.pnas.org/content/104/42/16432.abstract)

Comment: Thanks so much, that's what I'm looking for. If you post your comment as an answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Upon request I post my comment as an answer:

There is an interesting article on this topic by Dorian M. Raymer and Douglas E. Smith:

*[Spontaneous knotting of an agitated string](http://www.pnas.org/content/104/42/16432.abstract)*